# How to use application:get_env() in Erlang/OTP?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, mochiweb

I created a mochiweb instance

```
src/
   |-- Makefile
   |-- room.erl
   |-- myserver.app
   |-- myserver.erl
   |-- myserver_app.erl
   |-- myserver_deps.erl
   |-- myserver_sup.erl
   |-- myserver_web.erl
   `-- uuid.erl
```

in `myserver_web.erl` I am able to access the application config

```
{ok, "0.0.1"} = application:get_key(vsn),
```

However in `room.erl`, I am not able to access the application config (specifically the `env` list).

```
undefined = application:get_key(vsn),
```

The supervisor does not start the room, nor do I want it too.

I'm new to OTP and I realize I'm probably doing something stupid, but I would really appreciate anyone's help.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

From [the Erlang documentation about the application:get_key/1-2 function](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html#get_key-1):

> Returns the value of the application
>   specification key Key for Application.
>   If the application argument is
>   omitted, it defaults to the
>   application of the calling process.

What's the application of my_server_web.erl? What's the application of room.erl?

> If the specified application is not
>   loaded, or the specification key does
>   not exist, or if the process executing
>   the call does not belong to any
>   application, the function returns
>   undefined.

Is the key specified? Is the application loaded?

Regarding the "env" key, you can use [the application:get_env/1 function](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html#get_env-1) instead.

Comment: +1 for showing the documentation. It helps a lot to understand the why's?!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out... The answer is quite stupid and I feel silly posting, but I hope someone else can benefit from me.

I was actually doing everything right (as are all the other answers), but I was using mochiweb's auto [reloader](http://erldocs.com/R14Bextra/mochiweb/reloader.html) and not actually stopping the server.  Once I did that everything was fine.

DOH!  Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_key(myserver, vsn)` instead. Note that the application needs to be loaded first.

Comment: ahhh, I forgot to mention, but I did that as well... and still undefined.  I used application:load(myserver) and I get back an error that it's already loaded. I use application:get_key(myserver, vsn) and still get undefined....