# Where do values from a config or application:set_env go? How do I get them?

Tags: erlang

I am working with the Erlang MQTT broker which uses cuttlefish to generate .config files for the application. The values in the config files end up being used in the application, so for example at one point the Opts variable will contain values from the config file like {ssl_opts, {more, values, here}}...}

Where are these values stored? How could I access them from inside a function? I am generally confused about the whole process, and help or links would greatly help my understanding!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The module [aplication](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html) from application [kernel](http://erlang.org/doc/man/kernel_app.html) is responsible for it. The values are accessible using [`application:get_env/1,2,3`](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html#get_env-1) functions and [`application:get_all_env/0,1`](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html#get_all_env-0)
and [`application:get_key/1,2`](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html#get_key-1) and [`application:get_all_key/0,1`](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html#get_all_key-0) as well. It is stored in named public [`ets`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html) table `ac_tab` (`[set, public, named_table, {read_concurrency,true}]`). To be precise, internal module `application_controller` is responsible for it.

The values from various configs (`.app` and `.config` files) are merged (mainly `env` key) and loaded into the `ac_tab` table in [`application:load/1,2`](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html#load-1) which is prerequisite for [`appliaction:start/1,2`](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/kernel/application.html#start-1). Read more details in [7 Applications](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html) chapter of [OTP Design Principles User's Guide](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/users_guide.html).

Your question is partialy answered also in [How to use `application:get_env()` in Erlang/OTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4112339).